# Django create divs using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have a Django application that calls a ajax request..The ajax request gets a list of products and I generate the html page using Jquery...

Everything working fine except loading the images..The images are served in a separate webserver...

Here is the code -

```
    slicedata.forEach(function(e,i,a){

        var obj = e;
        $("<div id = product" + i + " class = product-cards  </div>").appendTo('#product-container')
        $("<div id = product" + i + "left  class = product-cards-left>  <a href={% static 'product-images/" + obj.image_caption + "' %}      >Image #1</a> </div>").appendTo('#product' + i)
        $("<div id = product" + i + "right class = product-cards-right </div>").appendTo('#product' + i   )
        $("<label><b>  NAME: <b></label>  <label>" + obj.name + "</label><br>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
        $("<label><b>  Price: <b></label>  <label>" + '$' + obj.price + "</label><br>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
        $("<label><b>  Old Price: <b></label>  <label>" + '$' + obj.old_price + "</label><br>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
        $("<label><b>  Author Name: <b></label>  <label>" + obj.author_name + "</label>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
    })
```

Problem:-
The images need to be loaded from a separate place and when I use the below code
the final substitution looks like this -

```
<a href="/online_static/product-images/%22%20%2B%20obj.image_caption%20%2B%20%22">Image #1</a>


$("<div id = product" + i + "left  class = product-cards-left>  <a href={% static 'product-images/" + obj.image_caption + "' %}      >Image #1</a>
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your images are uploaded correct in the other place you can create a global variable on your settings file named "IMAGES_SERVER" and use this variable into your template file.

Answer (score 0):

`static` is a reverence for Django to the local static folder. I would recommend using Lara advice and set a global variable.